# When using Objection, implementation of custom protocol crashes with unrecognized selector

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I am defining a custom protocol:

```
@protocol NGSAuthProvider <NSObject>
- (BOOL)isReady;
- (BOOL)isSessionValid;
- (void)login;
- (void)logout;
- (NSString *)accessToken;
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end
```

I want to have different providers.  So one is a Facebook provider:

```
@interface NGSFacebookAuthProvider : NSObject <NGSAuthProvider>
@end

@interface NGSFacebookAuthProvider () <FBSessionDelegate>
@property BOOL ready;
@property(nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSArray *permissions;
@end

@implementation NGSFacebookAuthProvider
//Implementation of fbLogin, fbLogout and the methods in NGSAuthProvider that forward calls to self.facebook
- (NSString *)accessToken
{
  return [self.facebook accessToken];
}

@end
```

I setup [Objection](https://github.com/atomicobject/objection) to bind from my class to the protocol.

```
@interface NGSObjectionModule : ObjectionModule
@end

@implementation NGSObjectionModule

- (void)configure 
{
   self bind:[NGSFacebookAuthProvider class] toProtocol:@protocol(NGSAuthProvider)];
}
@end
```

I setup the Global Injector:

```
@implementation NGSAppDelegate
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ObjectionModule *module = [[NGSObjectionModule alloc] init];
  ObjectionInjector *injector = [Objection createInjector:module];
  [module release];

  [Objection setGlobalInjector:injector];
}
```

I am using this in my RootViewController like this:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController
@end

@interface RootViewController ()
@property(nonatomic, retain) id<NGSAuthProvider> authProvider;
@end

@implementation RootViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.authProvider = [[Objection globalInjector] getObject:@protocol(NGSAuthProvider)];
}

- (void)processConfig {
  NSString *token = [self.authProvider accessToken];
  // use the access token
}
@end
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
2011-07-26 21:46:10.544 ngs[6133:b603] +[NGSFacebookAuthProvider accessToken]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x30c7c
2011-07-26 21:46:10.546 ngs[6133:b603] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[NGSFacebookAuthProvider accessToken]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x30c7c'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00e825a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00fd6313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00e8417b +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00df3966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x00df3522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   ngs                                 0x0000324b -[RootViewController processConfig] + 731
    6   ngs                                 0x000041a2 __33-[RootViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke_0 + 50
```

So my class implements the protocol.  It successfully is assigned to `id<NGSAuthProvider>`. I tried contructing `[[NGSFacebookAuthProvider alloc] init]` explicitly instead of using [Objection](https://github.com/atomicobject/objection) and it still crashed.

I tried looping through the selectors using `objc/runtime.h` methods to see which selectors are there but the only thing it finds is `initialize`:

```
- (void)logSelectors:(id)obj
{
    int i=0;
    unsigned int mc = 0;
    Method * mlist = class_copyMethodList(object_getClass([obj class]), &mc);
    NSLog(@"%d methods", mc);
    for(i=0;i<mc;i++)
        NSLog(@"Method no #%d: %s", i, sel_getName(method_getName(mlist[i])));

    free(mlist);
}
```

This has to be something simple that I am missing.  I use protocols defined by Cocoa and don't have this issue.  I have defined custom protocols for `UIViewController`-based delegates without issue.

I am stumped as to why Obj-C runtime can't find my methods! If I change `id<NGSAuthProvider>` to `NGSFacebookAuthProvider` and construct it explicitly then it all works.

SOLUTION:

The problem was I misunderstood how to bind to a protocol.  One way that works is:

```
@implementation NGSObjectionModule

- (void)configure 
{
  [self bind:[[[NGSFacebookAuthProvider alloc] init] autorelease] toProtocol:@protocol(NGSAuthProvider)];
}
@end
```

What I would like to do is bind a class to a protocol, but Objection probably wouldn't know the initializer to call?

Comment: Hi,I referred [http://ravelantunes.com/blog/mature-dependency-injection/].  But  [ - (void)configure {
    [self bind:[MyUserService class] toProtocol:@protocol(UserService)];
} ]   has an Error in Defining class  .   Your Solution worked !!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you're trying to use the static class method (denoted because you've got a +) instead of a method run on an instance of your object (which is what you've written it as, with a -)

Comment: I don't see where I am using a class method.

Comment: Me either. But somehow you are, right? Maybe you think you have an instance of an object but it's a pointer to the type itself (that's how class methods work under the hood I assume)

Comment: You comment about calling a static class method got me thinking.  The problem is how I am configuring Objection.  I thought I was setting it up to use a class object to instantiate an instance when requested for a protocol.  I have to actually create an instance when configuring it.  I will update the question to include the solution.  Now I see in the debug output that it couldn't find `+[NGSFacebookAuthProvider accessToken]`.

Answer (score 0):

Chris,

You could use Objection's meta class bindings that allows you to bind a meta class to a protocol and invoke class methods against the meta class instance.

For example,

```
[self bindMetaClass:[NGSFacebookAuthProvider class] toProtocol:@protocol(NGSAuthProvider)];
```

But only if you want to use class methods. Otherwise you can use the protocol bindings against a share instance.

Comment: I am not quite sure why you would bind a protocol to the class object.  So would the class object have to implement the protocol?

Comment: The protocol reflects the interface (it doesn't have to actually, but you'll get compiler warnings if you don't) of the meta class. The protocol simply acts as a binding mechanism so that Objection knows what object to bind a to property. Since there isn't a way to define a property that reflects the interface of the meta class the protocol is used to do that. See, https://github.com/atomicobject/objection and read the meta class binding section.

Comment: Ok, well that isn't what I wanted (i.e. class methods).  I had several different implementations of the `NGSAuthProvider` protocol and I wanted to configure Objection to construct an instance of a specific class when requested for a protocol.  So I wanted `[self bind:[NGSFacebookAuthProvider class] toProtocol:@protocol(NGSAuthProvider)]` to cause Objection to create an instance of `NGSFacebookAuthProvider` but it instead provided the class object.

Comment: Ah, yes. In this case you could use a shared instance `[self bind:[NGSFacebookAuthProvider sharedProvider] toProtocol:@protocol(NSGAuthProvider)]` or use a provider mechanism to build an instance and return it: `[self bindProvider:[[[CarProvider alloc] init] autorelease] toClass:[Car class]]` or `[self bindBlock:^(JSObjectionInjector *context) {
      // Manually build object
      return car;          
    } toClass:[Car class]];
}`

Comment: If my class has `objection_register_singleton(Class)` then I don't have to implement the `sharedProvider` class property, right?

Comment: Yes, if Objection is responsible for creating that object.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue as I was using

```
[self bind:[MyClass class] toProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

The right way for it to work is

```
[self bindClass:[MyClass class] toProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```